# reducing the size of time boxes

Tags: flutter, calendar, containers

I am bulding an app with flutter, I have an agenda page where the admin can pick the date from the calendar and choose the available times for the appointment. The data will be stored in the database in order for the user to check which time is available to book the appointment. My problem is related to the boxes that contains the available times that the admin can select. I want to make them smaller and i want to have the possibility to pick different time slots for the same date (for example from 9:00 to 12:00 and from 14:00 to 17:00). Any help would be much appreciated. Here is what i have done so far:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:api_cache_manager/utils/cache_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:questione_di_metodo/pages/timeRange.dart';
import 'package:time_range/time_range.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import '../models/login_response_model.dart';
import '../models/slots_request_model.dart';
import '../models/slots_response_model.dart';
import '../services/api_service.dart';


class AgendaPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AgendaPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AgendaPage> createState() => _AgendaPageState();
}

class _AgendaPageState extends State<AgendaPage> {
  static const orange = Color(0xFFFE9A75);
  static const dark = Color(0xFF333A47);
  static const double leftPadding = 50;
  static const double timeRangeFontSize = 10.0;
  static const double timeRangeBoxSize = 0.1;

  final _defaultTimeRange = TimeRangeResult(
    const TimeOfDay(hour: 14, minute: 00),
    const TimeOfDay(hour: 15, minute: 00),
  );
  TimeRangeResult? _timeRange;
  DateTime? selectedDate;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timeRange = _defaultTimeRange;
  }

  void saveDateTime() async {
    if (selectedDate != null && _timeRange != null) {
      final cacheData = await APICacheManager().getCacheData("login_details");
      if (cacheData != null) {
        final loginResponse = LoginResponseModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(cacheData.syncData));

        final startTime = DateTime(
          selectedDate!.year,
          selectedDate!.month,
          selectedDate!.day,
          _timeRange!.start.hour,
          _timeRange!.start.minute,
        );
        final endTime = DateTime(
          selectedDate!.year,
          selectedDate!.month,
          selectedDate!.day,
          _timeRange!.end.hour,
          _timeRange!.end.minute,
        );

        final slotsRequest = SlotsRequestModel(
          userId: loginResponse.userId,
          date: DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").format(selectedDate!),
          timeSlots: [
            TimeSlot(
              startTime: DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").format(startTime),
              endTime: DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").format(endTime),
            ),
          ],
        );

        try {
          final response = await APIService.createSlots(slotsRequest);
          // Handle the response if necessary
          print('SlotsResponseModel: ${response.toJson()}');
        } catch (error) {
          // Handle the error if the API request fails
          print('Error creating slots: $error');
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Future<DateTime?> selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 1),
    );
    return picked;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Agenda'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final DateTime? date = await selectDate(context);
                  if (date != null) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedDate = date;
                      _timeRange = _defaultTimeRange;
                    });
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Seleziona Data'),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            if (selectedDate != null) ...[
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints) {
                  final timeRangeWidth = constraints.maxWidth - leftPadding * 1;
                  final timeRangeHeight = timeRangeWidth * timeRangeBoxSize;

                  return CustomTimeRange(
                    fromTitle: SizedBox(
                      width: timeRangeWidth / 4,
                      height: timeRangeHeight,
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'DALLE',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: timeRangeFontSize,
                            color: dark,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    toTitle: SizedBox(
                      width: timeRangeWidth / 4,
                      height: timeRangeHeight,
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'ALLE',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: timeRangeFontSize,
                            color: dark,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    titlePadding: leftPadding,
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      color: dark,
                      fontSize: 10,
                    ),
                    activeTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: orange,
                      fontSize: 10,
                    ),
                    borderColor: Colors.blue,
                    activeBorderColor: dark,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    activeBackgroundColor: dark,
                    firstTime: const TimeOfDay(hour: 8, minute: 00),
                    lastTime: const TimeOfDay(hour: 20, minute: 00),
                    initialRange: _timeRange,
                    timeStep: 30,
                    timeBlock: 30,
                    onRangeCompleted: (range) => setState(() => _timeRange = range),
                    onFirstTimeSelected: (startHour) {},
                  );
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: saveDateTime,
                  child: const Text('Salva'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Custom Time range Class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:time_range/time_range.dart';

class CustomTimeRange extends TimeRange {
  static const double timeRangeBoxSize = 0.5;
  static const double customTimeRangeBoxSize = 0.25;

  CustomTimeRange({
    required Widget fromTitle,
    required Widget toTitle,
    required double titlePadding,
    required TextStyle textStyle,
    required TextStyle activeTextStyle,
    required Color borderColor,
    required Color activeBorderColor,
    required Color backgroundColor,
    required Color activeBackgroundColor,
    required TimeOfDay firstTime,
    required TimeOfDay lastTime,
    required TimeRangeResult? initialRange,
    required int timeStep,
    required int timeBlock,
    required void Function(TimeRangeResult?) onRangeCompleted,
    required void Function(TimeOfDay) onFirstTimeSelected,
  }) : super(
    fromTitle: fromTitle,
    toTitle: toTitle,
    titlePadding: titlePadding,
    textStyle: textStyle,
    activeTextStyle: activeTextStyle,
    borderColor: borderColor,
    activeBorderColor: activeBorderColor,
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    activeBackgroundColor: activeBackgroundColor,
    firstTime: firstTime,
    lastTime: lastTime,
    initialRange: initialRange,
    timeStep: timeStep,
    timeBlock: timeBlock,
    onRangeCompleted: onRangeCompleted,
    onFirstTimeSelected: onFirstTimeSelected,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final timeRangeWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
        final timeRangeHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
        final customTimeRangeHeight = timeRangeHeight * customTimeRangeBoxSize;

        return Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              left: titlePadding,
              top: (timeRangeHeight - customTimeRangeHeight) / 2,
              child: Container(
                width: (timeRangeWidth - titlePadding * 2) / 2,
                height: customTimeRangeHeight,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                  color: backgroundColor,
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: fromTitle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              right: titlePadding,
              top: (timeRangeHeight - customTimeRangeHeight) / 2,
              child: Container(
                width: (timeRangeWidth - titlePadding * 2) / 2,
                height: customTimeRangeHeight,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                  color: backgroundColor,
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: toTitle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                width: timeRangeWidth,
                height: timeRangeHeight,
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the output
[Admin's agenda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9CLO.png)